# Does Python unittest support customization for the report?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I like the fact that the unit test class will print out the nice summary about what pass and fail; although I can't see on the official documentation, how do you customize that output.

I see the msg parameter for the assert, which means that I can print a descriptive message when the assert trigger (test fail), but what if you want to include a summary on success?

Comment: It depends on how you actually run your tests, but you can see an example of how a report can be generated by looking at the `TestProgram`, `TextTestRunner`, and `TestResult` classes in `unittest.py`.

Comment: Thanks; is there a practical example about how to actually change the report? This is the first time that I work with unittest in python so I am looking for some examples. I did try to make a class where I inherit from TestResult but I can't get anything on screen

Comment: You would edit the output from `TestTextRunner.run`, but that only applies if you are running your tests by running `unittest.py` as a script.